# Java Android Gson convert boolean to int from response server

Tags: java, android, gson

Help me, guys!
Please, advise a simple solution to convert type boolean from server to int in Android :)
When I log in, i get respone from server like this :

```
{"status":{"error":0,"code":200,"message":"OK"},"response":{"profile":{"id":114,"username":"k@gmail.com","full_name":"k","phone":"9999999","verified":1,"admin":0,"allow_dev":false,"company":{"id":9,"name":"ООО \"Фингерз медиа\"","email":"info@fingers.by","sample":null,"logo":"http://storage.guardian-glass.fingersmedia.by/0cb56968b3cec1bba301db8d51d1015e.jpg"}},"access_token":"15629e234e04a54a5a44ef2aa4eccb1d"}}
```

Then I get `undefined exception: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected NUMBER but was BOOLEAN`

This happens because of JsonElement "**allow_dev**" is *boolean* from server, and in Android I have "**allow_dev**" like *int*.

This is login method :

```
 private void login(String email, String pass) {
    showProgress();
    JsonObject params = new JsonObject();
    params.addProperty("username", email);
    params.addProperty("password", pass);
    UserOperationsTask task = new UserOperationsTask(UserOperationsTask.TaskMode.MODE_LOGIN, params) {
        @Override
        public void onLoadFinished(Bundle res) {
            hideProgress();
            String errorMessage = res.getString(UserOperationsTask.RESULT_ERROR_STRING);
            if (errorMessage != null) {
                showMessage(getString(R.string.login_error), getString(R.string.server_request_error));
            } else {
                String json = res.getString(UserOperationsTask.RESULT_JSON_STRING);
                if (json != null) {
                    JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
                    JsonObject responseData = parser.parse(json).getAsJsonObject();
                    JsonObject companyObj = responseData.getAsJsonObject("profile").getAsJsonObject("company");
                   }
                setRegisteredMode();
            }
        }
    };
    task.execute(this);
}
```

This method parse response and I tried to convert allow_dev type from boolean to int, but I dont understand whether I'm doing right?

```
private Bundle parseProfileResponse(Context context, JsonObject responseData) {
    Log.d(TAG, "parseProfileResponse");

    // I tried convert allow_dev type from boolean to int
    String allow_dev_server = String.valueOf(responseData.get("allow_dev"));
    boolean b = allow_dev_server.equals("true");
    int allow_dev = b ? 1 : 0; // true == 1
    Profile profile;
    profile = GsonHolder.getGSONInstance().fromJson(responseData.getAsJsonObject("profile"), Profile.class);
    profile.allow_dev = allow_dev;

    Bundle res = new Bundle();
    res.putParcelable(RESULT_OBJ, profile);
    res.putString(RESULT_JSON_STRING, responseData.toString());
    try {
        Cache.saveToCache(context, profile);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "parseAuthResponse RemoteException: " + e.toString());
        res.putString(RESULT_ERROR_STRING, context.getString(R.string.database_error));
    } catch (OperationApplicationException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "parseAuthResponse OperationApplicationException: " + e.toString());
        res.putString(RESULT_ERROR_STRING, context.getString(R.string.database_error));
    }
    return res;
}
```

I have to get "**allow_dev**" convert it in *int* and write to database.

Comment: Why do you need it to be `int` at the client side?

Comment: Instead of
String allow_dev_server = String.valueOf(responseData.get("allow_dev"));
    boolean b = allow_dev_server.equals("true");
you can try
boolean b = responseData.get("allow_dev").getAsBoolean();

Gson uses reflection, so it is sometimes problematic to use custom setters.
You can use Jackson that is much helpful in these cases.

Comment: Lyubomyr Shaydariv, I need to write this value in sqlite db and there must to stored in integer type(boolean dont support)

Comment: Debanjan, thanks, I agree it looks better, but it old project and i cant change this library, I just have to add "allow_dev" mode, and I need advise...

Comment: @nicolasasinovich Can you not use `Jsonelement` and its subclasses, but use custom mappings (POJOs) instead?

Comment: @Lyubomyr Shaydariv, I'm sorry, but how can it hepl me?

Comment: @nicolasasinovich More clean code, static typing instead of dynamic "get by hardcoded name" (+ autocomplete can work easily in your IDE) + some tricks with type adapters to convert from `boolean` to `int` and vice versa automatically.

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv thank you for your advise!

Comment: @nicolasasinovich If you don't mind, I can provide an example with detailed comments for the exact JSON you have provided, so you could fine-tune it up to your needs.

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv, Yes, sure! It would be brilliant!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can switch to mappings, you can use everything static typing can give you, comparing to weakly "typed" `JsonElement` and its subclasses. It has several advantages: compile-time checking, more robust code, IDE support, etc. The major disadvantage is that you have to write custom mappings, however you there tools (online as well) that can *try to generate* simple mapping classes based on the given sample JSON (for example, a very popular tool here: http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/).

Now, let's create some mappings. The mappings like the ones below are used rarely: `final` fields (used for "server responses" that are no supposed to be modified programmatically; Gson can assign such fields anyway); `null` for non-primitives and some hacks for primitive type defaults values to cheat the compiler (like `Integer.value(0)` but not simply `0`: otherwise, `javac` may inline constants, thus Gson cannot affect them); no getters/setters (data-transfer objects are just data bags, but yes, getters can work better). Anyway, you can use your style, and the followings mappings are used for demonstration purposes (the mappings code has even compact formatting: one property per line collapsing the annotations).

```java
final class Response<T> {
    final Status status = null;
    final T response = null;
}

final class Status {
    final int error = Integer.valueOf(0);
    final int code = Integer.valueOf(0);
    final String message = null;
}

final class ProfileAndAccessToken {
    final Profile profile = null;
    @SerializedName("access_token") final String accessToken = null;
}

final class Profile {
    final int id = Integer.valueOf(0);
    final String username = null;
    @SerializedName("full_name") final String fullName = null;
    final String phone = null;
    final int verified = Integer.valueOf(0);
    final int admin = Integer.valueOf(0);
    @SerializedName("allow_dev") @JsonAdapter(BooleanToIntTypeAdapter.class) final int allowDev = Integer.valueOf(0);
    final Company company = null;
}

final class Company {
    final int id = Integer.valueOf(0);
    final String name = null;
    final String email = null;
    final String sample = null;
    final URL logo = null;
}
```

Note two annotations above:

- `@SerializedName` -- this annotation can "rename" fields so you can use even special characters (however it's discouraged, and it's typically used to map incoming JSON property names to javaCamelNamingConventions).
- `@JsonAdapter` -- this annotation can "attach" a special type adapter to a certain field, so that it could convert JSON properties to the given field and vice versa.

Now let's implement a type adapter that can convert incoming `boolean` values to local `int` values and vice versa. Note that type adapters work in streaming manner, so you have to read JSON tokens stream on fly during read, and, of course, generate JSON tokens stream during write.

```java
final class BooleanToIntTypeAdapter
        extends TypeAdapter<Integer> {

    // Public constructors may be evil, and let expose as less as possible
    // Gson can still instantiate this type adapter itself  
    private BooleanToIntTypeAdapter() {
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public void write(final JsonWriter out, final Integer value)
            throws IOException {
        // If the given value is null, we must write the `null` token to the output JSON tokens stream anyway in order not to break JSON documents
        if ( value == null ) {
            out.nullValue();
            return;
        }
        // Let's assume that we can accept either 0 or 1 that are mapped to false and true respectively
        switch ( value ) {
        case 0:
            out.value(false);
            break;
        case 1:
            out.value(true);
            break;
        default:
            // Or throw an exception as fast as we can
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot convert " + value + " to a boolean literal");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Integer read(final JsonReader in)
            throws IOException {
        // Peek the next token type, and if it's null, then return null value too
        if ( in.peek() == NULL ) {
            return null;
        }
        // Otherwise parse the next token as boolean and map it either to 1 or 0
        return in.nextBoolean() ? 1 : 0;
    }

}
```

That's all you need in Gson. Now, for you entire JSON, since the response mapping class is generic, you have to tell Gson what the `T` is. Gson accepts `java.lang.reflect.Type` in the `fromJson` method, and this type can hold both raw and parameterized types, so Gson could (de)serialize more accurately.

```java
private static final Type profileAndAccessTokenResponse = new TypeToken<Response<ProfileAndAccessToken>>() {
}.getType();

final Response<ProfileAndAccessToken> response = gson.fromJson(JSON, profileAndAccessTokenResponse);
System.out.println(response.response.profile.allowDev);
System.out.println(gson.toJson(response, profileAndAccessTokenResponse));
```

Output:

> 0
>   {"status":{"error":0,"code":200,"message":"OK"},"response":{"profile":{"id":114,"username":"k@gmail.com","full_name":"k","phone":"9999999","verified":1,"admin":0,"allow_dev":false,"company":{"id":9,"name":"ООО \"Фингерз медиа\"","email":"info@fingers.by","logo":"http://storage.guardian-glass.fingersmedia.by/0cb56968b3cec1bba301db8d51d1015e.jpg"}},"access_token":"15629e234e04a54a5a44ef2aa4eccb1d"}}

Note that the first line is `0`: this what is generated with `BooleanToIntTypeAdapter`. Backing to your code:

```java
String allow_dev_server = String.valueOf(responseData.get("allow_dev"));
boolean b = allow_dev_server.equals("true");
int allow_dev = b ? 1 : 0; // true == 1
Profile profile;
profile = GsonHolder.getGSONInstance().fromJson(responseData.getAsJsonObject("profile"), Profile.class);
profile.allow_dev = allow_dev;
```

Can be replaced with simple:

```java
final Profile profile = GsonHolder.getGSONInstance().fromJson(responseData.getAsJsonObject("profile"), Profile.class)
// now `Profile.allowDev` is 0 or 1 automatically
```

Note that `responseData` can be replace with a particular mapping, so you could even not parse at that line: probably you might simply pass the whole `response` object as a class mapping rather that `JsonObject` in your `parseProfileResponse` -- it would be more robust.

Comment: Its realy work!)) Thank you so much for your tutorial!!!  Eeeeeее))) You are a cool man, you realy help me!!! Sorry I do not have enough reputation to vote for your answer)

Comment: @nicolasasinovich No problem, I'm glad I could help you out!